# Clean String containing float number using Regex to just number and decimal

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to clean inputted float value that user entered to actual float w/o extraneous values. This is being done in php.

Original value could be:

1200.2 or

1200.2space or

space1200.2space or

1,200.2

Want cleanedvalue to be just the numbers and decimal 1200.2

```
$cleanedvalue=preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]*/","",$orig_value);
```

Currently it's outputting 1

Comment: Your code works fine https://3v4l.org/VsKNK

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the verification, turns out another line was messing up the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick, here is the example code I tested on http://www.writephponline.com/

```
<?php
    $string = "100,20 0,.25 ";
    $string = preg_replace("/\,|\s/", "", $string);
    print $string;
```

the pattern "\,|\s" will match any comma or whitespace in the string and replace it with "" an empty character

here is the output from the above code:

```
100200.25
```